# IntelliJ IDEA and Pycharm : wrong text formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am on `Windows 10, 64-bit`, latest version of both OS and the IDEs.

When I start them that's what I've got, in both cases, what could it be?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA support answered me at this link:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208579405-Help-with-unreadable-text?page=1#community_comment_203976450

[image]